# Detecting Page Changes in pdf using WebView in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, webview, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm displaying a pdf stored in a `Document` directory in a `WebView`, i want to detect the changes of the pages within the pdf. I searched about it and got to know about the methods `goBack()` and `goForward()` but it didn't work for me, i think they are for switching between the files in `webView` but i want to detect the `page switching` within a current loaded pdf file. i didn't have a code for this to show as i'm still trying to figure it out. any sample code with an explanation will be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to `scrollView` to navigate particular position of page, like below.

```
let selectedPage: CGFloat = 2; // i.e. Go to page 5

let pageHeight: CGFloat = 1000.0; // i.e. Height of PDF page = 1000 px;

let y: CGFloat = pageHeight * selectedPage;

let pageOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: y)
self.webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(pageOffset, animated: true)
```

Comment: how it will be triggered?

Comment: For this you have to create WebView with navigation bar button next and previous, and calculate logic according to it.

Comment: won't it work without the button press? because most of the time user just scroll instead through the webView instead of pressing button to go to next?

Comment: actually what i have to do is to run a timer and calculate the time user spend on every single page of pdf.